# Finding cheapest path on a graph, cost determined by max-weight of used nodes

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, path-finding

I have a graph G with a starting node S and an ending node E. What's special with this graph is that instead of edges having costs, here it's the nodes that have a cost. I want to find the way (a set of nodes, W) between S and E, so that max(W) is minimized. (In reality, I am not interested of W, just max(W)) Equivalently, if I remove all nodes with cost larger than k, what's the smallest k so that S and E are still connected?

I have one idea, but want to know if it is correct and optimal. Here's my current pseudocode:

```
L := Priority Queue of nodes (minimum on top)
L.add(S, S.weight)

while (!L.empty) {
    X = L.poll()
    return X.weight if (X == G)
    mark X visited
    foreach (unvisited neighbour N of X, N not in L) {
        N.weight = max(N.weight, X.weight)
        L.add(N, N.weight)
    }
}
```

I believe it is worst case O(n log n) where n is the number of nodes.

Here are some details for my specific problem (percolation), but I am also interested of algorithms for this problem in general. Node weights are randomly uniformly distributed between 0 and a given max value. My nodes are Poisson distributed on the R²-plane, and an edge between two nodes exists if the distance between two nodes is less than a given constant. There are potentially very many nodes, so they are generated on the fly (hidden in the foreach in the pseudocode). My starting node is in (0,0) and the ending node is any node on a distance larger than R from (0,0).

EDIT: The weights on the nodes are floating point numbers.

Comment: If a node _N_ has a weight _w_, then you could assign all edges ending at _N_ the weight _w_. Doing so for any vertex would give you a digraph on which you could perform the regular graph algorithms. Indeed given your real goal, j_random_hacker's answer is just the perfect way :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting from an empty graph, you can insert vertices (and their edges to existing neighbours) one at a time in increasing weight order, using a [fast union/find data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) to maintain the set of connected components.  This is just like the [Kruskal algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm) for building minimum spanning trees, but instead of adding edges one at a time, for each vertex v that you process, you would combine the components of *all* of v's neighbours.

You also keep track of which two components contain the start and end vertices.  (Initially comp(S) = S and comp(E) = E; before each union operation, the two input components X and Y can be checked to see whether either one is either comp(S) or comp(E), and the latter updated accordingly in O(1) time.)  As soon as these two components become a single component (i.e. comp(S) = comp(E)), you stop.  The vertex just added is the maximum weight vertex on the the path between S and E that minimises the maximum weight of any vertex.

**[EDIT: Added time complexity info]**

If the graph contains n vertices and m edges, it will take O(n log n) time to sort the vertices by weight.  There will be at most m union operations (since every edge could be used to combine two components).  If a simple disjoint set data structure is used, all of these union operations could be done in O(m + n log n) time, and this would become the overall time complexity; if path compression is also used, this drops to O(m A(n)), where A(n) is the incredibly slowly growing inverse Ackermann function, but the overall time complexity remains unchanged from before because the initial sorting dominates.

Assuming integer weights, Pham Trung's binary search approach will take O((n + m) log maxW) time, where maxW is the heaviest vertex in the graph.  On sparse graphs (where m = O(n)), this becomes O(n log maxW), while mine becomes O(n log n), so here his algorithm will beat mine if log(maxW) << log(n) (i.e. if all weights are very small).  If his algorithm is called on a graph with large weights but only a small number of *distinct* weights, then one possible optimisation would be to sort the weights in O(n log n) time and then replace them all with their ranks in the sorted order.

Comment: This is a good solution for my problem. It happens to be very fast and easy to do, because of how I generate nodes. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome :)  I've added some info on the worst-case running time bounds.

Answer (score 3):

This problem can be solved by using **binary search**.

Assume that the solution is `x`, Starting from the start, we will use BFS or DFS to discover the graph, visit only those nodes which have weight <= `x`. So, in the end, if Start and End is connected, `x` can be the solution. We can find the optimal value for `x` by applying binary search.

Pseudo code

```
int min = min_value_of_all_node;
int max = max_value_of_all_node;
int result = max;
while(min<= max){
    int mid = (min + max)>>1;
    if(BFS(mid)){//Using Breadth first search to discover the graph.
       result = min(mid, result);
       max = mid - 1;
    }else{
       min = mid + 1;
    }
}
print result;
```

**Note**: we only need to apply those weights that exist in the graph, so this can help to reduce time complexity of the binary search to O(log n) with n is number of distinct weights

If the weights are float, just use the following approach:

```
List<Double> listWeight ;//Sorted list of weights
int min = 0;
int max = listWeight.size() - 1;
int result = max;
while(min<= max){
    int mid = (min + max)>>1;
    if(BFS(listWeight.get(mid))){//Using Breadth first search to discover the graph.
       result = min(mid, result);
       max = mid - 1;
    }else{
       min = mid + 1;
    }
}
print listWeight.get(result);
```

Comment: It does not take the different distance metrix (max and not sum) into account as far as I can see.

Comment: @amit, I see, I have understood the problem incorrectly :)

Comment: This looks promising! Unfortunately the weights are floats, not ints. Binary search should work anyway though, but I'll have to use `while(max - min > delta)` instead, right? Will the complexity of this algorithm be O(n log((max-min)/delta))?

Comment: @DrPhil you are right about normal binary search for float, but for your case, we can handle it in same manner with integer.

Comment: @DrPhil as I stated in the note, we only need to care about the weights exist in the graph. Updated code to demonstrate this point :)